# how can make a side menu in android

Tags: android, listview

Hi I want to make a menu like

1. in first it shows a list like in drawer layout.
2. when i click on any item the list should populate in right side. in this case both parent and right side list visible.
3. if i click on any item of right side list then it should again populate in right side.

In this way i want to populate menu upto three level.

i want to show like when we open menu inside window 7 or like in window xp.

if anyone have any clue then please help. i can not post the image because my reputation is below 10.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome, please post what you have done already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved my problem myself.

Now i use three fragment inside a linear layout. on click on first list item i load the second list fragment and on click on second list item i load a third listfragment.